# Run Ubuntu Core 16 image for Raspberry Pi 3 in QEMU

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-core, arm, qemu

I am trying to run **Ubuntu Core 16 image for Raspberry Pi 3** in QEMU but it does not work. I followed this steps:

- Mount **Ubuntu Core 16 image for Raspberry Pi 3**
- extract **kernel.img**
- Start **qemu**

  ```
   qemu-system-arm -kernel ./kernel.img \
    -cpu arm1176 \
    -m 256 \
    -M versatilepb \
    -no-reboot \
    -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" \
    -drive "file=pi3.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw" \
    -redir tcp:2222::22
  ```

QEMU Starts but nothing else happens. No Error Messages in console.

Does somebody know how to arm Ubuntu Core (arm Arch) in QEMU?

Best Regards Rustam

Comment: If I want to use verstailepb I need to patch the kernel and then recompile it. Is there any another way to emulate Ubuntu Core (armhf) with QEMU?

Answer (score 0):

Are you have seabios installed? (dpkg -l|grep seabios)
Try to use any "seabios" roms.  (-bios path/to/anybios.rom)
I'm not tested it but it can be helpfull.

https://github.com/virtualopensystems/qemu-arm/tree/master/roms

Comment: How do you  mean it?

Comment: I do not use *versatilepb* anymore, I use raspi2 Machine instead. "-M raspi2".  Raspberry does not have any BIOS, it uses "config.txt" file for configuration